# How to count how many tries are used in a loop

Tags: python, macos, loops, while-loop

For a python assignment I need to ask users to input numbers until they enter a negative number. So far I have:

```
    print("Enter a negative number to end.")
    number = input("Enter a number: ")
    number = int(number)
    import math
    while number >= 0:
        numberagain = input("Enter a number: ")
        numberagain = int(numberagain)
        while numberagain < 0:
            break
```

how do I add up the number of times the user entered a value

Comment: I'm assuming this is Python 3, but you really should specify, because most of the details of what you're trying to do are different between 2.x and 3.x.

Answer (score 3):

```
i = 0
while True:
    i += 1
    n = input('Enter a number: ')
    if n[1:].isdigit() and  n[0] == '-':
        break
print(i)
```

The `str.isdigit()` function is very useful for checking if an input is a number. This can prevent errors occurring from attempting to convert, say `'foo'` into an `int`.

Comment: I never knew about the isdigit() function, that's super helpful.

Comment: I think using `str.isdigit` is not a good idea here, it causes unhandled exceptions for such inputs as `'-7 '` and `'spam123'`.

Comment: The pythonic way to check if something can converted to an `int` and, if so, do so is to `try:` it.

Comment: @abarnert I know, but for some reason I don't like `try` statements - maybe it just takes up too many lines...

Comment: @Volatility: When answering here, especially for novices, I try to avoid pushing my own idiosyncrasies and stick to idiomatic Python. I hate if-expressions, love to abuse generator functions, etc., but I feel guilty if I influence other people to make Guido cry. And you're bending over pretty far here, writing an explicit integer parser, and then calling the built-in one…

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools

print('Enter a negative number to end.')
for i in itertools.count():
  text = input('Enter a number: ')
  try:
    n = int(text)
  except ValueError:
    continue
  if n < 0:
    print('Negative number {} entered after {} previous attempts'.format(n, i))
    break
```

The solution above should be robust to weird inputs such as trailing whitespace and non-numeric stuff.

Here's a quick demo:

```
wim@wim-desktop:~$ python /tmp/spam.py
Enter a negative number to end.
Enter a number: 1
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: foo123
Enter a number: i am a potato
Enter a number: -7
Negative number -7 entered after 4 previous attempts
wim@wim-desktop:~$
```

Comment: Yes - good catch, I tested it in 2.x with a `from __future__ import print_function`, which I later removed but forgot about the `raw_input` / `input` thing.